# Why does dynamically creating list items not work for the 10th item?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, html-lists

I am dynamically creating tabs as items of a list. For that I am using an input field called *'amount'*. But I noticed some unwanted behavior for the 10th item. When using the arrow keys to increase or decrease the value of *'amount'* the 10th item gets skipped and only gets created when I increase the value to 11, which creates both the 10th and 11th value at the same time. Every other value seems to work fine. Even inputting the number 10 and pressing enter works as intended, which is why I am even more confused.

This is my code:

```js
const tabs = document.getElementById("tabs");
const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
var prevAmount = 0;

amount.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (amount.value < 1) {
        amount.value = 1;
    }

    if (amount.value > prevAmount) {
        while (tabs.children.length < amount.value) {
            var newTab = document.createElement("li");
            newTab.textContent = tabs.children.length + 1;
            newTab.setAttribute("class", "tab");

            tabs.appendChild(newTab);           
        }
    } else {
        while (tabs.children.length > amount.value) {
            tabs.removeChild(tabs.lastChild);
        }
    }

    prevAmount = amount.value;
});

amount.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
        <div id="amount-and-tabs-container">
            <div class="container" id="amount-container">
                <label id="amount-label" for="amount">Amount:</label>
                <input type="number" id="amount" value="1" min="1">
            </div>

            <div class="container" id="tabs-container">
                <ul class="tabs" id="tabs"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--<script src="form.js" defer></script>-->
    <script src="tabs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're performing a lexicographical comparison and `'9' > '10'`. If you want to do a numerical comparison, parse or convert to a number first, e.g. `const value = Number(amount.value);`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oh, wow, thank you. I did not know that about Javascript